# Lightning-Network Channel not being closed and balance in "limbo"

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-closing-channels

My node [Caffeine](https://1ml.com/node/022d509049e143b1c5fc5383210acb97a3e5a4b0e0d31dd4c920eee92a4aacd312) has a channel in pending status (close txid: 0de535ea74d72a952157640187b5a207fe977870a5c9b92f0aa99b9707c94779) with [The Cave](https://1ml.com/node/02ae3c06f6db6a87ea874ef7ba86c87ab0041eabf6d8be0594582505b1fd5d7ee8) since months!
My local balance is stuck in a "limbo" and I have no idea what to do...
How to finalize the closure? How to get the balance out of the limbo?

[image]

Comment: your transaction is not on the mem pool which meant that your close transaction is not committed. With implementation are you using?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo LND. What shall I do? Why doesn't unstuck itself if it's not in the mem pool?

Comment: if the tx is not in the mempool you have not close the channel

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I don't understand. Is there something I can do at this point?

Comment: try to contact the lnd team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have open an issue on the GitHub repo of LND and a solution was found, here is the link https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/5341